# How to delete multiple files in sharepoint using csom

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I'm downloading files from a particular folder in a list. Everything is working. Then my boss asked me to the delete files after downloading.

Here's what i've tried.

```
            SecureString str = new SecureString();
            string cnf = Util.Cipher(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cnf"].ToString());
            foreach (char ch in cnf.ToCharArray())
            {
                str.AppendChar(ch);
            }

            string user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["user"].ToString();
            SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(user, str);
            string siteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["site_url"].ToString();
            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                ctx.Credentials = credentials;
                string library = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sharepoint_library"].ToString();

                List mylibrary = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(library);
                FileCollection files = mylibrary.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl(sharepointFolder).Files;

                ctx.Load(files);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in files)
                {
                    FileInformation fileinfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, file.ServerRelativeUrl);

                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                    using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(dir + "\\" + file.Name, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        fileinfo.Stream.CopyTo(filestream);
                    }
                    file.DeleteObject();
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                }

            }
```

This is the error I'm getting.

The collection was modified. Enumeration operation may not execute.

P.S. everything is working until I added this line of code.

```
file.DeleteObject();
```

Comment: how do i delete it then if i don't use deleteobject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply modify the code snippet as below:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;

namespace CSOM
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev"))
            {
                string password = "*****";
                string account = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
                var secret = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in password)
                {
                    secret.AppendChar(c);
                }
                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);

                List mylibrary = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
                FileCollection files = mylibrary.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl("/sites/dev/shared documents/folder1").Files;

                ctx.Load(files);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in files)
                {
                    FileInformation fileinfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, file.ServerRelativeUrl);

                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                    using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream("D:" + "\\" + file.Name, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        fileinfo.Stream.CopyTo(filestream);
                    }

                }
                files.ToList().ForEach(file => file.DeleteObject());
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            };

        }


    }
}
```

Add last two line to delete files from folder after downloading,I have tested and it works in my side.

Comment: ToList() method does not contain a definition on filecollection.

Comment: @ErrolPaleracio, ToList() needs to reference using System.Linq, I will update my code above to add using for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using

```
 File.Delete(dir + "\\" + file.Name);
```

Comment: I'm deleting the file in the sharepoint. Does this code work?