# CSOM PowerShell delete multiple files from SharePoint

Tags: powershell, loops, sharepoint-online, csom

My PowerShell script is looping through every file in directory and uploads it to SharePoint Online if it is missing/has changed. All works fine, now I'd like to delete extraneous files from SharePoint to have real synchronization functionality. As user mentioned in other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57685765) I am receiving this error after I tried to use DeleteObject():

```
The collection was modified. Enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Here's my code:

```
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($library)
$ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
$Context.Load($ListItems)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$SPfiles = @()
#Iterate through each document in the library
ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems) {
  $Data = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([Ordered] @{
    FileName  =   $ListItem.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"]
  })
  if ( -not(Test-Path -Path "$local_dir\$($Data.FileName)")) {
    $ListItem.DeleteObject()
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    Continue
  }
  $SPfiles += $Data
}
```

how can I delete SharePoint files (ideally in this loop), or do I have to write another loop and query/execute $ListItems variable after every DeleteObject() call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `foreach` loop to delete items, use `for` loop instead.

```
for ($i = $ListItems.Count-1; i >= 0; i--){
 $ListItems[i].DeleteObject()
 $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```